# Change padding using jquery to class but only to clicked item

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

OK, so I am sorry if this question is repeated BUT I really could not figure answer.

O have menu with classes, and I want that when I click on some menu items `.menuitem > a`
that link have more paddingBottom.

So I managed to use `.click` function and animate function but that add padding to entire class ( all menu items ).
What I need is adding padding only to THAT CLICKED menu.

Code that make padding to all menu items ( entire class )

```
$(".menuitem" ).click(function() {
    $('.mainNav > ul > li > a').animate({paddingBottom:"+=17px"});
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **when I click on some menu items `.menuitem > a` that link have more `paddingBottom`**

Within the click handler, the particular `.menuitem` element that was clicked can be referred to by `this`. Thus, using `$(this)` you can use [jQuery's DOM traversal method(s)](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/) to move from that element to the related one you want to animate.

If the anchor is a child of the `.menuitem` element that you are binding the click handler to then the simplest way to get a reference to that anchor is with the [`.find()` method](http://api.jquery.com/find):

```
$( ".menuitem" ).click(function() {
    $(this).find("a").animate({paddingBottom:"+=17px"});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this key word to select your 'a' tag which you click on it now 'only'

```
$('.menuitem').click(function(){
  $(this).find('a').animate({'padding':'+=17px'});
});
```

or more specific

```
 $('.menuitem li').click(function(){
  $(this).find('a').animate({'padding':'+=17px'});
});
```